# A problem about convergence of distributions in the total variation metric

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

For this problem, we consider the space of random vectors in $L^2(\Omega)$. More specifically, we consider the following space of probability measures:
$$\mathcal{L}:=\{\mu \sim X \,\,:\,\, X \in L^2(\Omega), E[X]=0, E[X^2]< \infty  \}$$
Consider the [Total Variation metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures), $d_{TV}$, in $\mathcal L$. For simplicity, we will write $X_n \overset{TV}{\longrightarrow} X$, instead of $d(\mu_n, \mu)\to 0$, as $n \to \infty$ (Assuming $X_n \sim \mu_n$ and $X\sim \mu$).

Define:
$$X_n = \sum_{j=1}^n W_j\left(U_{j,n} + N_{j,n} \right), \quad n \in \mathbb N,$$
where:

- $(W_j)_{j=1}^\infty$ is a fixed realization of a stationary and ergodic sequence in the following sense:
  \begin{equation}\label{erg}\tag{E}
  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n f(W_{j}) \,\overset{a.s}{\longrightarrow}\, E[f(W_1)],\quad (n \to \infty)
  \end{equation}
  Moreover, suppose $E[W_j]=0$, for all $j$.
- $(U_{j,n})_{j\in \mathbb N}\overset{iid}{\sim}Bernoulli(\lambda/n)$, for each $n =1,2,\cdots$.
- $(N_{j,n})_{j\in \mathbb N}\overset{iid}{\sim}Normal(0, \sigma^2_n)$, for each $n =1,2,\cdots$ such that $\sigma^2_n \to 0$, as $n \to \infty$. Futhermore, $(U_{j,n})_{j\in \mathbb N}$ and $(N_{j,n})_{j\in \mathbb N}$ are independent.

Suppose that $X_n \overset{TV}{\longrightarrow} X$, as $n \to \infty$, for some $X$. Now define:
$$Y_n = \sum_{j=1}^n W_j U_{j,n}Z_j, \quad n \in \mathbb N,$$
where

- $(Z_{j})_{j\in \mathbb N}\sim t_5$, i.e., a sequence iid according to a $t_5$ distribution.
- The $W's$ and the $U's$ have the same descriptions given above. Finally, $(U_{j,n})_{j\in \mathbb N}$ and $(Z_{j})_{j\in \mathbb N}$ are independent.

I am trying to show whether it is true that $X_n \overset{TV}{\longrightarrow} X$ implies:
$$Y_n \overset{TV}{\longrightarrow} X, \quad (n \to \infty)$$

It is possible to show that $X$ has a [compound Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution), but I don't think this is crucial for my purpose.